# How to add a Global runtime service to System.ComponentModel.Container?

Tags: .net, components, containers

Suppose the .NET Component Model.

The Container class has `GetService(Type service);`

But I'm asking myself, how can I register **Global Services** accessible to all added `Components` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this you'll need to create a class that derives from `Container`.  The class `Container` only supports service for the `GetService` call and that's `IContainer`.  There is no way to extend this except for sub-typing and overriding the GetService method.

However this is only of very limited value as the method `GetService` is protected.  This means it's not usable by general components as they don't have access to this member.